# Sitecore api that returns sign in page?

Tags: api, sitecore

Anybody knows the Sitecore api method that returns the sign in url as below?

```
 https://dev.site/signin?item=%2fmyaccount&user=extranet\Anonymous&site=website
```

The above url is rendered when the user clicks on my account link before logging in.

If the method is already available in sitecore api, I would rather use it instead of writing my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.RedirectToLoginPage(context);
```

That will redirect to the Sitecore login page. `context` is the HttpContext of your request.